# tkinter: kill process started with `root.after` when `root.destory()` is called?

Tags: python, user-interface, asynchronous, tkinter, parallel-processing

I think I have a conceptual problem. I want to start a process with `root.after` and terminate the GUI program and the process at the same time. Currently, the process started with `root.after` still keeps going after the GUI has been destroyed. How do I need to do this correctly?

MWE: iterate over a list and ask whether to replace 1 with 0s. Program can be closed properly by pressing `exit` when all 1s are replaced. Otherwise the process for `f` keeps going even when the GUI is gone:

```
import tkinter as tk

l = [0,1,1,0,1,0,1]

root = tk.Tk()
var = tk.IntVar()
termination=False

def update_l(i):
    l[i] = 0

def g(i):

    def replace():
        update_l(i)
        b1.destroy()
        b2.destroy()
        var.set(var.get()+1)

    def keep():
        b1.destroy()
        b2.destroy()
        var.set(var.get()+1)

    b1 = tk.Button(root, text='replace', command=replace)
    b1.pack()

    b2 = tk.Button(root, text='keep', command=keep)
    b2.pack()

    root.wait_variable(var)
    f()

def f():
    print(l)
    for i, j in enumerate(l):
        if termination:
            break
        if j:
            g(i)
            break

def terminate():
    global termination
    termination = True
    root.destroy()

b = tk.Button(root, text='exit', command=terminate)
b.pack()

root.after(200, f)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: ***start a process with `root.after`***: You don't start a process, you start a Tkinter independent **infinite loop**.

Comment: Okay, I see. And how do I terminate it?

Comment: @stovfl: no, you don't start an "tkinter independent infinite loop" with `root.after`. `root.after` simply puts an item on a queue. You are correct, though, that this doesn't start a process.

Comment: Replace `command=lambda: root.destroy()` with a custom callback where you set a termination global flag. Inside `g()` and `f()` check this flag and break if true.

Comment: @stovfl Ok, I have tried your suggestion, but I must have done it wrong, as it does not change anything. I have edited the code in my post. I added a variable `termination` and a function `terminate()`. Can you tell me in how far my solution is different from what you meant? Thank you. I did not know where to place a `break` in `g`, since it has no loop.

Comment: Looks Ok, verify if `termination` inside `def f()` get set to True

Comment: @stovfl The point `if termination:` is never reached. I guess that is because `root.wait_variable(var)` never fires when none of `replace` and `keep` are pressed. I added `var.set(var.get()+1)` to `terminate` and that fixed it.

Comment: OK, I assumed it gets released on `.destroy()`